# How to use a menu

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, menu, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int food, product, total;
    double price;
    cout << "     Welcome To Maggie’s Shopping Cart Calculator!" << endl;
    char option; // user's entered option will be saved in this variable
    do{
    //Displaying Options for the menu
    cout << " 1) Please add an item to your cart " << endl;
    cout << " 2) Final Total Amount" << endl;
    cout << " 3) Quit the program" << endl;   //Prompting user to enter an option according to menu
    cout << " Please select an option : ";
    cin >> option;  // users option
    total = price;
    if (option == 1) // Checking if user selected option 1
    {
        cout << " Please enter item and the price : " << endl;
        cin >> food;
        cin >> price;
        cout << " Total amount so far: " << price << endl;
        }
        else if (option == 2)
            cout << "Total Amount so Far: " <<  total << endl;
        else if (option == 3) // Checking if user selected option 2
        {
            cout << " End Shopping Cart! " << endl;
        }
    }
        while (option != 3);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is my code that I have, I just continues to repeat the menu, even when I select an option help! The assignment is to have three options for the user to choose, and the menu should be repeated after choice 1 was selected. My code isn't letting me enter in any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified ur code , check it out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int  product, total=0;int flag =1;string food;
double price;
cout << "     Welcome To Maggie’s Shopping Cart Calculator!" << endl;
int option; // user's entered option will be saved in this variable
do{
//Displaying Options for the menu
cout << " 1) Please add an item to your cart " << endl;
cout << " 2) Final Total Amount" << endl;
cout << " 3) Quit the program" << endl;   //Prompting user to enter an option              according to menu
cout << " Please select an option : ";
cin >> option;  // users option

if (option == 1) // Checking if user selected option 1
{
    cout << " Please enter item and the price : " << endl;
    cin >> food;
    cin >> price;total = total + price ;
    cout << " Total amount so far: " << total  << endl;
    }
    else if (option == 2)
        cout << "Total Amount so Far: " <<  total << endl;
    else if (option == 3) // Checking if user selected option 2
    {
        cout << " End Shopping Cart! " << endl;
        flag=0 ;

    }


  }
    while ( flag== 1);

    return 0;
}
```

hope this is helpful

Comment: This is super helpful, but can you explain the flag part for me, I've seen examples with it but I don't understand it.

Comment: edited , just setting flag to 0 will end the loop , less while loop will continue

Comment: Oh okay cool, so the system is like spazing out when I enter the name and the price of the product it like plays the menu really fast an infinite amount of times how would I fix it

Comment: because the food is of type string and u declared it as int,  editted the code

Comment: Okay so I should make it a string!

Comment: So it gives me the little red line under >>,  so cin >> food; is now an error

Comment: Well thank you for all your help!!! ITs still not working but I"ll play with it and see what I can do!!

Answer (score 0):

You defined the option variable as char, while you compare it as int later on.. Try to change its definition to int

Comment: Thank you for such a fast reply I"ll give it a try now!!

Comment: So the assignment is to have three choices. Add to 1. cart, 2. total and 3. quit. If 1 is chosen  the user enters name and then price. Then display the total price so far. Then display the menu again. if 2 is chosen, give the total so far and then display the menu again. if 3 is chosen give the total and quit.  must use loops, no global variables,  use getline() (I"m not sure what this is), the menu should always show after each option unless 3 is selected.